# PayPal create order using nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, paypal

I need to create an order using an npm for paypal . I tried it locally and I need it so that when i click an endpoint it creates the order.Below is what i have tried . Thanks in advance :)

```
const paypal = require('@paypal/checkout-server-sdk');
  
// Creating an environment
let clientId = "<<PAYPAL-CLIENT-ID>>";
let clientSecret = "<<PAYPAL-CLIENT-SECRET>>";

// This sample uses SandboxEnvironment. In production, use LiveEnvironment
let environment = new paypal.core.SandboxEnvironment(clientId, clientSecret);
let client = new paypal.core.PayPalHttpClient(environment);

// Construct a request object and set desired parameters
// Here, OrdersCreateRequest() creates a POST request to /v2/checkout/orders
let request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
request.requestBody({
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "100.00"
            }
        }
     ]
});

// Call API with your client and get a response for your call
let createOrder  = async function() {
    let response = await client.execute(request);
    console.log(`Response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
    
    // If call returns body in response, you can get the deserialized version from the result attribute of the response.
    console.log(`Order: ${JSON.stringify(response.result)}`);
}
createOrder();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your code work as-is to create the order? If it works, then what you need to do next is create a URL route for it, using express or similar, and have that endpoint be called by a browser with the client JS for approval: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

You can find a full stack example in [the Checkout integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/). Be sure to include capture route response error handling (onApprove function in first link above) since that's not in the full stack example currently.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer . The code works like this but when i try to click the endpoint in my aws lambda it doesnt give me any logs of error , and doesnt give me any result . If you have any suggestions about this case :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "click the endpoint". Endpoints are URLs. If the code "works", what does it output? If it doesn't output anything, add more logging.

Comment: When i run the code locally it outputs the created order but no sign when i hit the api gateway endpoint .